# Cpp template of recursive/nested structs

Tags: c++, templates, structure, metaprogramming

What exactly compiler creates when following structure is used in given code?

```
template<>
struct TaskTraits<task_1>
{
typedef numlist<event_1,
        numlist<event_2,
        numlist<event_3,
        numlist<event_4,
        numlist<event_5,
            null_numlist> > > > >
    events;
};
```

The structure is used in following template:

```
template<typename event_manager, size_t NL_H, typename NL_TAIL>
struct HandlerCaller<event_manager, common::numlist<NL_H, NL_TAIL> >
{
    static void call(MaskType event)
    {
        if (event & NL_H)
        {
            typedef typename event_manager::template EventHandler<NL_H> t_handler;
            t_handler::handle();
        }
        HandlerCaller<event_manager, NL_TAIL>::call(event);
    }
};
```

and it's called from:

```
HandlerCaller<EventManager<task>, typename TaskTraits<task>::events >::call(event);
```

Numlist is pretty simple and defined as:

```
template<size_t H, typename T>
struct numlist
{
    enum { head = H };
    typedef T tail;
};
```

I understand that call function iterates through nested numlist structs till the head match the event but how many HandlerCaller structs will be instatiated and how many numlists?

Does compiler create 6 HandlerCaller (5 events + nullevent) with different versions of nested numlist?  Or it creates only one TaskTraits with all nested numlist structs inside and then pass only pointers to specific numlist inside TaskTraits in HandlerCaller (not possible because there is no object of TaskTraits, just structure definition, right?)? How many HandlerCaller would be created then? Only one? Maybe I consider it as too much similar as normal programming but all these templates seem to be confusing sometimes. Thank you for explanation.